# error from InlineKeyboardMarkup and InlineKeyboardButton

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

This code has some errors. First in  `InlineKeyboardMarkup inline = new InlineKeyboardMarkup();` it says;

> inlinekeyboardmarkup does not contain a constructor that takes 0 argument.

Second, in `InlineKeyboardButton("text","https://t.me/bec00l")` it says;

> inlinekeyboardbutton does not contain a constructor that takes 2 argument

I'm using Telegram.Bot API version 15.5.1

```
 InlineKeyboardMarkup inline = new InlineKeyboardMarkup();
                    InlineKeyboardButton[] row1 =
                    {
                        new InlineKeyboardButton("text","https://t.me/bec00l")
                    };
                    inline.InlineKeyboard = new InlineKeyboardButton[][]
                    {
                        row1
                    };

                   bot.SendTextMessageAsync(ChatId, sb.ToString(), ParseMode.Default, false, false, 0, inline);
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: InlineKeyboardButton doesn't take any arguments. You should define a variable and assign it to new InlineKeyboardButton, and then set that variable's properties.

Answer (score 0):

You mustn't initialize `InlineKeyboardMarkup` except when you have initialized `InlineKeyBoardButton[][]` alraedy.

And in second problem:

> there isn't constructor that takes `(string, string)`

You can pass your arguments to `InlineKeyboardButton` properties in curly brackets `{}` that means you can pass your arguments (like custom constructor) instead of `()` that means default defined constructors,

Or use static method `InlineKeyboardButton.WithUrl`, like this:

```
InlineKetboardButton[] row1 = new InlineKetboardButton[] 
{
    // Without default constructors:
    new InlineKeyboardButton 
    { 
        // Set properties with arguments:
        Text = "text",
        Url = "https://t.me/bec00l"
    }, 
    
    // Second way:
    InlineKeyboardButton.WithUrl("text", "https://t.me/bec00l")
};

InlineKeyboardButton[][] buttons = new InlineKetboardButton[][]
{
    row1
};

// Define and Initialize
InlineKeyboardMarkup inline = new InlineKeyboardButton(buttons);

// Send message!
bot.SendTextMessageAsync(ChatId, sb.ToString(), ParseMode.Default, false, false, 0, inline);
```